# adding a fla file from ported flash project to haxe (openfl)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, haxe, openfl

What I want is to convert a flash project to an openfl project (which is written in haxe) in order to use its cross platform feature. I used [as3hx](https://github.com/vpmedia/AS3toHX) to convert actionscript classes of a flash project to haxe. Then I fix compile errors by hand, and fix a run time error too. When I compile the project, I see a blank black window, which means that graphics are not loaded. I convert the code and code is working fine, but I don't know what should I do with graphics. There is a *fla* file in flash project, which I don't know how to convert it to openfl.

Adobe Flash CC, which is the program used to write flash project, does the linkage of a symbol to a actionscript class, and I don't know how to do this in openfl.

In openfl, as far as I know, giving graphics to a class is done like this :

```
import openfl.display.Bitmap;
import openfl.display.BitmapData;
import openfl.display.Sprite;
import openfl.Assets;

class Main extends Sprite {

    public function new () {

        super ();
        var bd:BitmapData = Assets.getBitmapData("img/openfl.png");
        var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
        addChild(b);    
    
    }

}
```

Where the *openfl.png* is a graphical file in a special folder named img, which declared to be an assets path.

I use [HaxeDevelop](http://www.haxedevelop.org/) IDE.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just download trial version of Flash, open the FLA, extract what you need (images from **Library**, or export animation frames as own SWF). When you have the graphics (jpg/ png/ animated swf) then you load them into your haxe code as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use FLA files inside OpenFL, there's only support for SWF files exported by Flash from those FLA files:

http://www.openfl.org/learn/tutorials/using-swf-assets/

OpenFL's "native" SWF playback functionality is limited but for simple graphics and animations it's usable as long as you figure out what features are actually being supported and limit yourself to those.

Comment: Since you didn't provide any details about what you did I can't really help with that. Maybe you can try to build the official openfl swf example to see if it works in general? https://github.com/openfl/openfl-samples/tree/master/libraries/swf/SimpleSWFLayout